# Create 2 new fields using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

looking for some advice on making R code below produce the
desired results.  Any help would be much appreciated

Below is the logic, code, sample data and desired output.  Current code is not producing the desired results.  I can get the desired results using for loops but it takes too long

## Logic:

1. if the ID is the first ID encountered then group=1 and groupdate = date
2. else if not first ID and date - previous date > 10 or date - previous groupdate >10 then group=previous group # + 1 and groupdate = date
3. else if not first ID and date - previous date <= 10 or date - previous groupdate<=10 then group = previous group # and groupdate = previous date.

## Sample Code:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T,text='ID  DATE        ITEM
           1   1/1/2014    P1
           1   1/15/2014   P2
           1   1/20/2015   P3
           1   1/22/2015   P4
           1   3/10/2015   P5
           2   1/13/2015   P1
           2   1/20/2015   P2
           2   1/28/2015   P3
           2   2/28/2015   P4
           2   3/20/2015   P5')
df1

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, GROUP:={
     dt <- as.Date(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
     gr1 <-cumsum((dt-shift(dt, fill=dt[1L]))>10)+1L; list(gr1)} ,
        by =  ID]
df1[, GROUPDATE := DATE[1L] , by = .(GROUP, ID)]

df1
```

===============

```
# Desired output.
ID  DATE        ITEM    GROUP   GROUPDATE
1   1/1/2014    P1  1   1/1/2014
1   1/15/2014   P2  2   1/15/2014
1   1/20/2014   P3  2   1/15/2014
1   1/22/2014   P4  2   1/15/2014
1   3/10/2015   P5  3   3/10/2015
2   1/13/2015   P1  1   1/13/2015
2   1/20/2015   P2  1   1/13/2015
2   1/28/2015   P3  2   1/28/2015
2   2/28/2015   P4  3   2/28/2015
2   3/20/2015   P5  4   3/20/2015
```

Comment: you expected result for `ID == 2` does not match your spec in the Logic, e.g. `1/20/2015` to `1/28/2015` is less than 10, but still the `GROUP` number changes

Comment: It changed because date - previous groupdate is greater than 10 days.  If date - previous date or date - previous groupdate is greater that 10 it changes.

Comment: I made a mistake on the desired output - please see below.

Comment: Sorry, I rechecked and the out table is correct.  My logic may be off but I think is correct also..

Comment: ok, your input does not match in terms of DATE. I guess it should be `2014` in first 4 records for `ID == 1`

Comment: I corrected the input type O and reran the 
code and it is correct in all places except
for the third line for ID 2.  group should = 2 
and groupdate should = 1/28/2015 because 
date(1/28/2015) - prev groupdate(1/13/20) is greater
than 10. Any suggestions for getting that missing piece of logic in there?

Comment: code in my answer seems to give correct results

Comment: @Pele: Welcome at SO! Please note that you should accept the best correct answer to help others to find good answers quickly and to acknowledge the work of the author. THX :-)

Comment: IMHO, part 3 of the Logic (the _else_ part) should read _date - previous date <= 10 **and** date - previous groupdate<=10_ because _not (A or B) = not A and  not B_ (DeMorgan's Laws).

Comment: @Pele: are you aware that `df1` differs from your desired output in rows 3 and 4 of column `DATE`?

Answer (score 1):

This answer describes two approaches, one is iterative, the other one uses a *non-equi join*.

Although both return the desired output for the sample dataset provided by the OP *I feel they should be tested more thoroughly with larger datasets.*

#### Iterative approach

The OP has requested to increase a group counter by one

1. if there is a gap of more than 10 days between the actual date and the previous date, i.e., the date in the previous row,
   **- or -**
2. if there is a gap of more than 10 days between the actual date and the first day of the group (the "groupdate")

*for each `ID`*.

Condition (1) can be computed straightforward in one rush. Unfortunately, the first day of a group which is referenced in condition (2) may change when evaluating condition (2). So, this may require more than one pass to find the final solution.

The answer below evaluates condition (1) and uses this temporary solution to iteratively evaluate condition (2) until no more change in group assignment is observed.

The OP has supplied two different data.tables in his question. Here, we take the second one which includes the expected result:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- fread("ID  DATE        ITEM    GROUP   GROUPDATE
1   1/1/2014    P1  1   1/1/2014
1   1/15/2014   P2  2   1/15/2014
1   1/20/2014   P3  2   1/15/2014
1   1/22/2014   P4  2   1/15/2014
1   3/10/2015   P5  3   3/10/2015
2   1/13/2015   P1  1   1/13/2015
2   1/20/2015   P2  1   1/13/2015
2   1/28/2015   P3  2   1/28/2015
2   2/28/2015   P4  3   2/28/2015
2   3/20/2015   P5  4   3/20/2015")
```

The `DATE` and `GROUPDATE` columns need to be coerced to a Date class beforehand.

```
cols <- c("DATE", "GROUPDATE")
df2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, "%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols = cols]
```

Note, that there is an implicit assumption that the rows are ordered by `DATE` within each `ID`.

Now, we can start the computation. In order to compare the results, I have chosen different column names.

```
dt <- copy(df2) # just for convenience to easily switch between df1 and df2
# create group count for gaps of more than 10 days
dt[, grp := cumsum((DATE - shift(DATE, fill = 0)) > 10L), by = ID]
# set group date
dt[, gdt := first(DATE), by = .(ID, grp)]
# update group count according to conditon (2)
tmp <- dt[, cumsum((DATE - shift(gdt, fill = 0)) > 10L), by = ID][, V1]
# repeat as long as there changes in group counts
while (dt[, any(grp != tmp)]) {
  # complete update of group count
  dt[, grp := tmp]
  # set new group date
  dt[, gdt := first(DATE), by = .(ID, grp)]
  # update group count according to conditon (2)
  tmp <- dt[, cumsum((DATE - shift(gdt, fill = 0)) > 10L), by = ID][, V1]
}
dt
```

> ```
>     ID       DATE ITEM GROUP  GROUPDATE grp        gdt
>  1:  1 2014-01-01   P1     1 2014-01-01   1 2014-01-01
>  2:  1 2014-01-15   P2     2 2014-01-15   2 2014-01-15
>  3:  1 2014-01-20   P3     2 2014-01-15   2 2014-01-15
>  4:  1 2014-01-22   P4     2 2014-01-15   2 2014-01-15
>  5:  1 2015-03-10   P5     3 2015-03-10   3 2015-03-10
>  6:  2 2015-01-13   P1     1 2015-01-13   1 2015-01-13
>  7:  2 2015-01-20   P2     1 2015-01-13   1 2015-01-13
>  8:  2 2015-01-28   P3     2 2015-01-28   2 2015-01-28
>  9:  2 2015-02-28   P4     3 2015-02-28   3 2015-02-28
> 10:  2 2015-03-20   P5     4 2015-03-20   4 2015-03-20
> ```

#### Non-equi join

The conditions can be re-written: A row belongs to one group if the gap to the preceeding row does not exceed 10 days **and** the gap to the first row of the group does not exceed 10 days.

```
dt <- copy(df2)
# append row id 
dt[, rn := .I]
tmp <- 
  # non-equi join to find all rows which lie within a 10 days interval
  dt[dt[, .(ID, start = DATE, end = DATE + 10L)], 
     on = .(ID, DATE >= start, DATE <= end)][
       # aggregate for row id to find the earliest start date
       , min(DATE), by = .(ID, rn)][
         # create group id (starting at one for each ID)
         , rleid(V1), by = ID]
# append group id to original data.table
dt[, grp := tmp$V1][
  # set group date
  , gdt := first(DATE), by = .(ID, grp)]
dt
```

> ```
>     ID       DATE ITEM GROUP  GROUPDATE rn grp        gdt
>  1:  1 2014-01-01   P1     1 2014-01-01  1   1 2014-01-01
>  2:  1 2014-01-15   P2     2 2014-01-15  2   2 2014-01-15
>  3:  1 2014-01-20   P3     2 2014-01-15  3   2 2014-01-15
>  4:  1 2014-01-22   P4     2 2014-01-15  4   2 2014-01-15
>  5:  1 2015-03-10   P5     3 2015-03-10  5   3 2015-03-10
>  6:  2 2015-01-13   P1     1 2015-01-13  6   1 2015-01-13
>  7:  2 2015-01-20   P2     1 2015-01-13  7   1 2015-01-13
>  8:  2 2015-01-28   P3     2 2015-01-28  8   2 2015-01-28
>  9:  2 2015-02-28   P4     3 2015-02-28  9   3 2015-02-28
> 10:  2 2015-03-20   P5     4 2015-03-20 10   4 2015-03-20
> ```

**Step-by step explanation**

The idea is to find the "groupdate" a particular row belongs to in one operation. This is achieved by finding all possible 10 day intervalls a row may belong to and aggregating by taking the earliest start date for each row. This is been used to create the group is using the `rleid()` function.

The expression below creates a helper data.table containing the 10 day intervals

```
dt[, .(ID, start = DATE, end = DATE + 10L)]
```

> ```
>     ID      start        end
>  1:  1 2014-01-01 2014-01-11
>  2:  1 2014-01-15 2014-01-25
>  3:  1 2014-01-20 2014-01-30
>  4:  1 2014-01-22 2014-02-01
>  5:  1 2015-03-10 2015-03-20
>  6:  2 2015-01-13 2015-01-23
>  7:  2 2015-01-20 2015-01-30
>  8:  2 2015-01-28 2015-02-07
>  9:  2 2015-02-28 2015-03-10
> 10:  2 2015-03-20 2015-03-30
> ```

The non-equi join finds all rows which lie within any of the 10 day intervals:

```
dt[dt[, .(ID, start = DATE, end = DATE + 10L)], 
     on = .(ID, DATE >= start, DATE <= end)]
```

> ```
>     ID       DATE ITEM GROUP  GROUPDATE rn     DATE.1
>  1:  1 2014-01-01   P1     1 2014-01-01  1 2014-01-11
>  2:  1 2014-01-15   P2     2 2014-01-15  2 2014-01-25
>  3:  1 2014-01-15   P3     2 2014-01-15  3 2014-01-25
>  4:  1 2014-01-15   P4     2 2014-01-15  4 2014-01-25
>  5:  1 2014-01-20   P3     2 2014-01-15  3 2014-01-30
>  6:  1 2014-01-20   P4     2 2014-01-15  4 2014-01-30
>  7:  1 2014-01-22   P4     2 2014-01-15  4 2014-02-01
>  8:  1 2015-03-10   P5     3 2015-03-10  5 2015-03-20
>  9:  2 2015-01-13   P1     1 2015-01-13  6 2015-01-23
> 10:  2 2015-01-13   P2     1 2015-01-13  7 2015-01-23
> 11:  2 2015-01-20   P2     1 2015-01-13  7 2015-01-30
> 12:  2 2015-01-20   P3     2 2015-01-28  8 2015-01-30
> 13:  2 2015-01-28   P3     2 2015-01-28  8 2015-02-07
> 14:  2 2015-02-28   P4     3 2015-02-28  9 2015-03-10
> 15:  2 2015-03-20   P5     4 2015-03-20 10 2015-03-30
> ```

E.g., the interval `[2014-01-15, 2014-01-25]` includes rows 2, 3, and 4. On the other hand, row 4 (`DATE`: 2014-01-22) falls within three different intervals:
`[2014-01-15, 2014-01-25]`, `[2014-01-20, 2014-01-30]`, and `[2014-01-22, 2014-02-01]`

Now, we pick the interval with the earliest start date for each row:

```
dt[dt[, .(ID, start = DATE, end = DATE + 10L)], 
   on = .(ID, DATE >= start, DATE <= end)][
     , min(DATE), by = .(ID, rn)]
```

> ```
>     ID rn         V1
>  1:  1  1 2014-01-01
>  2:  1  2 2014-01-15
>  3:  1  3 2014-01-15
>  4:  1  4 2014-01-15
>  5:  1  5 2015-03-10
>  6:  2  6 2015-01-13
>  7:  2  7 2015-01-13
>  8:  2  8 2015-01-20
>  9:  2  9 2015-02-28
> 10:  2 10 2015-03-20
> ```

Subsequent rows with identical `V1` belong to the same group. So, we can create group ids by using the `rleid()` function.

```
tmp <- 
  dt[dt[, .(ID, start = DATE, end = DATE + 10L)], 
     on = .(ID, DATE >= start, DATE <= end)][
       , min(DATE), by = .(ID, rn)][
         , rleid(V1), by = ID]

tmp
```

> ```
>     ID rn        gdt grp
>  1:  1  1 2014-01-01   1
>  2:  1  2 2014-01-15   2
>  3:  1  3 2014-01-15   2
>  4:  1  4 2014-01-15   2
>  5:  1  5 2015-03-10   3
>  6:  2  6 2015-01-13   1
>  7:  2  7 2015-01-13   1
>  8:  2  8 2015-01-20   2
>  9:  2  9 2015-02-28   3
> 10:  2 10 2015-03-20   4
> ```

The final steps are then

```
# append group id to original data.table
dt[, grp := tmp$V1][
  # set group date
  , gdt := first(DATE), by = .(ID, grp)]
```

Comment: I will test this also -  thank you for the alt approaches!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to capture the date related logic in a vectorised function, see `groupDates(x)` bellow. I have used recursive logic for that function, may be there is a more optimal way to do it.

For the fields counting change you can use `cumsum`.

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T,text='ID  DATE        ITEM
           1   1/1/2014    P1
           1   1/15/2014   P2
           1   1/20/2014   P3
           1   1/22/2014   P4
           1   3/10/2015   P5
           2   1/13/2015   P1
           2   1/20/2015   P2
           2   1/28/2015   P3
           2   2/28/2015   P4
           2   3/20/2015   P5')

dt <- as.data.table(df1)

groupDates <- function(x) {
  x.prev <- c(head(x, 1), head(x, -1))
  x.diff <- abs(c(0, diff(x)))
  x.diff.big <- x.diff > 10 | x.diff == 0
  x.diff.prev.big <- c(TRUE, head(x.diff.big, -1))
  x[!x.diff.big & x.diff.prev.big] <- NA
  x <- safe.ifelse(!is.na(x), x, x.prev)
  d <- diff(x)
  if(min(d[d > 0]) < 10) {
    groupDates(x)
  }
  else {
    x
  }
}

dt[, date := as.Date(DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]
dt[, group.date := groupDates(date), ID]
dt[, previous.date := shift(group.date, fill = first(date)), ID]
dt[, group.i := 1:.N, ID]   
dt[, previous.date.interval := abs(date -previous.date) > 10, ID]
dt[, group := cumsum(previous.date.interval) + 1L, ID]
dt[, .(ID, DATE, group.date, group)]
#    ID      DATE group.date group
# 1:  1  1/1/2014 2014-01-01     1
# 2:  1 1/15/2014 2014-01-15     2
# 3:  1 1/20/2014 2014-01-15     2
# 4:  1 1/22/2014 2014-01-15     2
# 5:  1 3/10/2015 2015-03-10     3
# 6:  2 1/13/2015 2015-01-13     1
# 7:  2 1/20/2015 2015-01-13     1
# 8:  2 1/28/2015 2015-01-28     2
# 9:  2 2/28/2015 2015-02-28     3
#10:  2 3/20/2015 2015-03-20     4
```

Comment: welcome. you can accept and vote the answer if it works for you